# Accessing JavaScript variable outside of $.each() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble passing a variable declared in an $.each() function to Prototype function. I'm receiving the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: prices is not defined`

```
Compare.prototype.results = function (answers) {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            answers: answers
        },

        success: function (data) {

            $.each(data, function (index, dataItem) {

                var prices = [],
                    priceData = dataItem.pricing_term,
                    priceObj = JSON.parse(priceData);

                $.each(priceObj, function (term, pricing) {
                    prices.push(term, pricing);
                });

            });
            Compare.prototype.show(data, prices);
        }

    });
}
```

I want to be able to populate the prices variable and pass it to be used with the data that is originally returned from the ajax call. I am new to javascript, if there is a cleaner way to go about writing this please let me know.

Comment: Then declare the variable outside of `$.each`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's out of scope

```
Compare.prototype.results = function (answers) {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            answers: answers
        },

        success: function (data) {

            var prices = [];


            $.each(data, function (index, dataItem) {
                var priceData = dataItem.pricing_term,
                    priceObj = JSON.parse(priceData);

                $.each(priceObj, function (term, pricing) {
                    prices.push(term, pricing);
                });

            });

            // same scope

            Compare.prototype.show(data, prices);
        }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have declared your `prices` array within the scope of the first `&.each` function. This means you can only access the `prices` array in that function. You need to declare `prices` outside of the function, like so:

```
Compare.prototype.results = function (answers) {

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        answers: answers
    },

    success: function (data) {

        var prices = [];

        $.each(data, function (index, dataItem) {

               var priceData = dataItem.pricing_term;
               var priceObj = JSON.parse(priceData);

            $.each(priceObj, function (term, pricing) {
                prices.push(term, pricing);
            });

        });
        Compare.prototype.show(data, prices);
    }

});
}
```

This way, `prices` is available in any of the functions that are within the scope of the `success` function of the AJAX request.